# set php variable contains only selected array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have these array but I wanted it to echo an array only for the "watch" category and wanted to store the selected array in a PHP variable, I have to try to search the web to find the solution but no success.

```
$arr = [
    'status' => 1,
    'msg' => [
            'total_records' => 5,
            'total_pages' => 1,
            'page_number' => 1,
            'per_page' => 100,
            'return_count' => 5,
            'page_result' => [

                    0 => array
                        (
                            'items' => 200052001,
                            'code' => 501,
                            'category' => 'watch',
                            'price' => 50,
                            'stock' => 1,
                        ),

                    1 => array
                        (
                            'items' => 200052001,
                            'code' => 401,
                            'category' => 'shirt',
                            'price' =>3,
                            'stock' => 1,
                        ),

                    2 => array
                        (
                            'items' => 200052001,
                            'code' => 172758801,
                            'category' => 'watch',
                            'price' => 200,
                            'stock' => 1,
                        ),

                ],

        ],

    'errcode' => 0,
];
```

Comment: `foreach($arr['msg']['page_result'] as $out){if($out['category']=='watch'){//do something}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$watch_array = array();
foreach($arr["msg"]["page_result"] AS $k => $item) {
    if($item["category"] == "watch") {
        $watch_array[] = $item;
    }
}
```

You now have an array containing only the watch.

To display its content, use:

```
print_r($watch_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo Link**](https://3v4l.org/NrHtV).

Check this search function for your requirement. Its completely dynamic along with recursive nature.

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = [];
    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
            $results[] = $array;
        }
        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
$temp = search($arr, "category", "watch");
```

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#110120).

Comment: thanks man, this should do the trick. I'll set you in my list

Comment: sorry i got no reputation, i will go meet you all that help me if my software is finished.

Comment: You may [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that you believe is the best solution to your problem.